# Sphinx errors with Pydantic settings, does not generate documentation

Tags: python, python-sphinx, pydantic

I am trying to generate documentation with Sphinx (apidoc) but all the files that call the settings file, are not documented.

When I run the `make html` command I get these error messages

```
#...
 File "pydantic/env_settings.py", line 39, in pydantic.env_settings.BaseSettings.__init__
  File "pydantic/main.py", line 342, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.__init__
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 35 validation errors for Settings
app_name
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
kafka_broker
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
apicurio_uri
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
jwt_secret
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
#...
```

I create the settings with BaseSettings from Pydantic

`settings.py`

```py
class Settings(BaseSettings):
    app_name: str
    kafka_broker: str
    healthcheck_topic: str = "_healthcheck"

    # Apicurio
    apicurio_uri: str
    apicurio_journal_topic: str = "kafkasql-journal"

    business_rules_topic: str = "_message"

    jwt_secret: str
    jwt_expiration_sec: int = 24 * 60 * 60  # A day
    _jwt_algorithm: str = PrivateAttr(default_factory=lambda: "HS256")

    admin_username: str
    admin_password: str

    azure_auth_url: str
 
    class Config:
        try:
            env_file = '.env'
            env_file_encoding = 'utf-8'
            case_sensitive = False
        except:
            env_file = '.env_local'
            env_file_encoding = 'utf-8'
            case_sensitive = False


    def __init__(self, **data):
        super().__init__(**data)

        self._postgresql_conn = make_url(self.postgresql_conn_url)

    @property
    def postgresql_conn(self) -> URL:
        return self._postgresql_conn

    @property
    def jwt_algorithm(self) -> str:
        return self._jwt_algorithm


    @validator('redis_user', 'redis_password')
    def field_is_not_empty_if_not_null(cls, v):
        if v is not None and len(v) == 0:
            raise ValueError("Field cannot be empty string")

        return v

    _fields_not_empty = validator(
        'kafka_broker',
        'app_name',
        'apicurio_journal_topic',
        'business_rules_topic',
        'jwt_secret',
        allow_reuse=True
    )(field_not_empty)

    _fields_are_positive = validator(
        'cache_short_expiration_hours',
        'cache_medium_expiration_hours',
        'cache_long_expiration_hours',
        'jwt_expiration_sec',
        allow_reuse=True
    )(field_non_zero_positive)

    _fields_are_uri = validator(
        'apicurio_uri',
        'ticket_uri',
        allow_reuse=True
    )(field_is_uri)

    def build_api_definition(self) -> TicketApiDefinition:
        return TicketApiDefinition(

            webservice_endpoint=self.ticket_webservice_path,
            webservice_path=self.ticket_webservice_path,

            create_session=self.ticket_webservice_create_session_endpoint,

        )


@lru_cache
def get_settings():
    return Settings()
```

How can I solve it? Do I need to change something on sphinx or is it about settings?

Comment: Keep in mind for what Sphinx was designed for. For some projects it is just to big or complex. There are some much easier documentation tools wiht real out of the box autodoc features. Maybe you are better with `pydoctor` for example.

Comment: Thanks @buhtz I didn't know pydoctor, I will try it now

Comment: Thanks again @buhtz I tried pydoctor and at the moment it does the job, I keep trying with sphinx and hope to find the solution or someone will answer this question.

Comment: If you want help getting it to work with Sphinx, please provide a [mcve].